# Load a Power Pivot data model in a VSTO Excel application

Tags: c#, sql-server, vsto, powerpivot

I have an Excel [*document-level customisation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386107.aspx#doclevel) (VSTO, C# - but not an Add-In) whereby the user can dynamically retrieve data from a SQL Server database. Right now I place the results on a worksheet, but there could be more than a million rows.
Does anybody know if it's possible to load the data into the Power Pivot data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the VBA equivalent as [blogged](https://powerpivotpro.com/2014/07/adding-tables-to-a-model-from-vba-in-excel-2013/) about by Dany Hoter. It should be a good pattern to follow in C#:

```
Sub AddSQLtables()

‘One or more tables from a SQL server database

‘Relationships are detected if they are declared in the database

ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2 _

“Connection Name”, “”, _

“OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=<SQL server – name>;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2008R2” _

, “””DimCustomer””,””DimGeography”””, 6, True, True

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. I expected it to be much more complicated somehow.  The Dany Hoter link is very useful too.  Thanks - much appreciated.